# Any way to include custom fields in WP_Query results?

Tags: custom-field, wp-query

Looking for a way to include custom fields in the output of WP_Query. I am managing a site where nearly every post type has a lot of custom fields defined and it would be much nicer not to have to run get_post_custom in almost every loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to hook somewhere in the gazillion hooks available in [**`wp-includes/query.php`**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/query.php).

I would suggest something like this:

```
function my_always_get_post_custom( $posts ) {

    for ( $i = 0; $i < count($posts); $i++ ) {

        $custom_fields = get_post_custom( $posts[$i]->ID );
        $posts[$i]->custom_fields = $custom_fields;

    }

    return $posts;

}

add_filter( 'the_posts', 'my_always_get_post_custom' );
```

In this way you will always have your posts custom fields at hand in your **`$post` object** without having to bother to look for them every time you are setting up a loop. From now on, you can just access them using `$post->custom_fields` as a `multi-dimensional array`.

Answer (score 0):

`WP_Query` let you query posts based on key or values from the custom fields if you would like to get multiple values from custom fields use `wpdb` you can read more about [**here**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Examples_4).